# Ebay Australia Site ID invalid on Trading API (Modified EbayR)

Tags: ruby, soap, ebay-api

Every time I try and publish a product with `AddFixedPriceItem` with the Site ID set to Australia (15) I get the error response:

> :errors=>{:short_message=>"Input data is invalid.", :long_message=>"Input data for tag  is invalid or missing. Please check API documentation."

I tried every variation of the site ID ("AU", "Australia", 15, "15") and when i switch it to the US site ID (0) everything works perfectly. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Im using my own customised version of [EbayR](https://github.com/bjjb/ebayr) (because it didn't parse the xml correctly)

Anyway here is the full raw SOAP request:

Headers:

```
{
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL' => @compatability_level.to_s, # => 837
    'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME' => dev_id.to_s,
    'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME' => app_id.to_s,
    'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME' => cert_id.to_s,
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME' => @command.to_s,
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID' => @site_id.to_s, # => which is 15
    'Content-Type' => 'text/xml'
  }
```

the full body request is:

```
<AddFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>....</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <Item>
        <Title>dssddsheykduhfid</Title>
        <ListingDuration>GTC</ListingDuration>
        <ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>
        <Description>This is another test description with image</Description>
        <PrimaryCategory>
            <CategoryID>57989</CategoryID>
        </PrimaryCategory>
        <SKU>dfiuhdssdsdfggfmeesddffdeseddfda</SKU>
        <InventoryTrackingMethod>SKU</InventoryTrackingMethod>
        <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
        <PayPalEmailAddress>payments-facilitator@logicsaas.com</PayPalEmailAddress>
        <CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>
        <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
        <Country>AU</Country>
        <Currency>AUD</Currency>
        <DispatchTimeMax>4</DispatchTimeMax>
        <PostalCode>3194</PostalCode>
        <ReturnPolicy>
            <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
            <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
            <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>
            <Description>What! you dont want the product! .... ok</Description>
            <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
        </ReturnPolicy>
        <PictureDetails>
            <PictureURL>http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg</PictureURL>
        </PictureDetails>
        <ShippingDetails>
            <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
            <ShippingServiceOptions>
            <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
            <ShippingService>AU_eBayAusPost3kgFlatRateSatchel</ShippingService>
            <ShippingServiceCost>10</ShippingServiceCost>
        </ShippingServiceOptions>
    </ShippingDetails>
    <Site>15</Site>
    <Variations>
        <VariationSpecificsSet>
            <NameValueList>
                <Name>Size</Name>
                <Value>L</Value>
                <Value>S</Value>
            </NameValueList>
            <NameValueList>
                <Name>Color</Name>
                <Value>Red</Value>
                <Value>Blue</Value>
            </NameValueList>
        </VariationSpecificsSet>
        <Variation>
            <SKU>dfiuhdssdsdfggfmeesddffdeseddfdaOMG454fgfgfg</SKU>
            <StartPrice>100.99</StartPrice>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <VariationSpecifics>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Size</Name>
                    <Value>L</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Color</Name>
                    <Value>Red</Value>
                </NameValueList>
            </VariationSpecifics>
        </Variation>
        <Variation>
            <SKU>dfiuhdssdsdfggfmeesddffdeseddfdaOMG432325fgfgfg</SKU>
            <StartPrice>100.99</StartPrice>
            <Quantity>16</Quantity>
            <VariationSpecifics>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Size</Name>
                    <Value>L</Value>
                </NameValueList>
                <NameValueList>
                    <Name>Color</Name>
                    <Value>Blue</Value>
                </NameValueList>
            </VariationSpecifics>
        </Variation>
    </Variations>
</Item>
```

Also I bit the bullet and payed the 75 dollars for technical support, If I don't get a response here I'll paste the response from them for all to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool, so it seems like this was an ebay issue. They are trying to fix it at the moment. But they responded with a work around:

Hello Avin ,

Thank you for reporting this issue. I can reproduce the problem and I have forwarded this to our engineering team for further investigation. We will keep the ticket open in "Waiting-BugFix" status.

Actually SiteID is not a mandatory field. SiteID will be taken from the header if you don't pass it. As a workaround, please omit the field and continue listing.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Best Regards, 
eBay Developer Support